# Viewing events in FullCalendar ordered by event ID instead of start timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, fullcalendar

I have a calendar set up and when viewing the month view I want to display the events which have been created by their ID and not the time they are due to start.

Is this possible? And if so, how would I go about changing the code to display the events in this manner?

Comment: we need some code... table structure for example ;-)... sample data.

Answer (score 1):

Great solution!
I've used it and adapted it for my needs. I'm using JSON feeds.

Important: the first condition is to make sure all the events are sorted by start date.

Then, if you want to sort by title :

```
function segCmp(a, b) {
   var tryCmp = (b.msLength - a.msLength) * 100 + (a.event.start - b.event.start);
   if (tryCmp == 0) {
            return (a.event.title.toLowerCase() >= b.event.title.toLowerCase()) ? 1: 0;
    }
   return tryCmp;
}
```

I've also used it another way.
I've added a custom attribute to each event of the JSON feed called 'colOrder'(it could be anything) and gave it integer values (1,2,3...). 1 is for the first event I want to see, 2 for the second...

Then I customized the function to use the colOrder attribute to sort the events.

```
function segCmp(a, b) {
   var tryCmp = (b.msLength - a.msLength) * 100 + (a.event.start - b.event.start);
   if (tryCmp == 0) {
    if (!isNaN(a.event.colOrder) && !isNaN(b.event.colOrder))
            return (a.event.colOrder - b.event.colOrder);
    }
   return tryCmp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `ORDER BY id ASC` to your query.

Comment: This does not work, since fullcalender plugin will sort by the _id by default, no matter what order your "query output" is ordered

Answer (score 0):

no easy way to do this yet, but when this issue is implemented, should be easy:
http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=364

Answer (score 0):

Long time since last post, but just in case someone need it (like me):

change in fullcalendar.js

```
function segCmp(a, b) {
    return (b.msLength - a.msLength) * 100 + (a.event.start - b.event.start);
}
```

to

```
function segCmp(a, b) {
   var tryCmp = (b.msLength - a.msLength) * 100 + (a.event.start - b.event.start);
   if (tryCmp == 0)
      return (a.event.id - b.event.id);
   return tryCmp;
}
```

it worked for me